# Zurb Foundation Reveal Modal with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, zurb-foundation, refinerycms

I am using the Zurb Foundation CSS framework on a RefineryCMS site and I have a gallery page with a number of thumbnail images and I would like the the image to be a link that opens the reveal modal with a larger image and description inside it, basically my show page.

I have used the fancy_box plugin before which was really simple but cant figure this one out.

#### Index page

```
 <ul class="large-block-grid-4" id="galleries">
  <% @galleries.each do |g| %>
   <li>
    <%= link_to refinery.galleries_gallery_path(g), :remote => "true", :data => { :"reveal-id" => "modal", :"reveal-ajax" => "true" } do %>
      <%= image_fu g.image, "250x250" %>
    <% end %>
   </li>
  <% end %>
 </ul>
```

#### show.js.erb

```
$("#modal").html('<%= escape_javascript(render "modal", image: @image)%>') 
$('#modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
```

#### _modal.html.erb

```
<div id="modal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
  <h2><%=raw @gallery.title %></h2>
  <%= image_fu @gallery.image, "600x600" %>
  <%=raw @gallery.description %>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

#### Controller

```
def show
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use image tag inside link tag

```
  <%= link_to image_tag(g.image, "250x250"),"#" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but doesn't answer my question :)

Comment: can you please little bit elaborate what exactly you want to do .

Comment: you can do that by two way 1. through AJAX in that on click of image link an AJAX will be triggered and that will find information of that image and in response you will update the html and then you can invoke manulally create a show.js.erb $("#modal").html('<%= escape_javascript(render "show", image: @image)%>')
 $('#modal').foundation('reveal', 'open'); and the partial template you render will have html of show      2 Way is to have all the things on the html like if you have 10 image than 10 separate modal for them and all have distinct id .

Comment: i am doing the same thing with AJAX while showing details of an event in popup when click on the event in the calendar

Comment: That doesn't work, I have updated my question with your suggestion.

Comment: you are making a mistake put this <div id="modal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal></div> on the index page than in modal html remove <div id="modal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal> container. also verify that your AJAX is firing